# Upon loading, computer runs super slow until I run HWinfo

Tags: cpu, performance

After starting windows, the PC just stays slow, forever. Slow as in the cursor jumps around, music is played in slow motion. Like maybe 1/2 speed? Applications take forever to load etc.

What is odd is that it will go to normal speed after running HWInfo. As soon as the tests are done, the PC just works correctly.

CPU temp never gets above 60C

This is the current hardware:

- CPU: Ryzen 3700X
- Motherboard: AsusROG STRIX X570-E GAMING
- Graphics Card: MSI 390X
- RAM: G.SKILL 32GB DDR4 3200 RGB
- SSD 1: 1TB Samsung 970EVO M.2

For the motherboard, using latest bios, overclocking is off except for the ram settings which for some reason needed to be enabled to get the correct 3200 speed.

Comment: Is this a new problem or an old problem?

Comment: new motherboard, cpu, and ram. Reinstalled windows fresh. So while it's new to me, it's been a problem since day 1.

Comment: Does the problem exhibit itself, if you disable the memory overclocking. in order to rule out a configuration conflict?

Comment: Does Task Manager show high CPU usage, or high I/O, e.g. from an antivirus checking the disk?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik No high cpu, no high. Problem just instantly goes away after HWInfo checks the system

Comment: @Ramhound Disabled memory overclock. Problem still there.